# Opening Angular Material dialog in multiple windows application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm developing an `Angular 10` Material application, that should be running in a dual monitor environment.
I've created a window that is shown on the second monitor using `Window.open()` method.
How is it possible to open a `Material dialog` on this newly created window?
Thanks.

EDIT: I'm interested of having a single instance of the application that manages both windows, similar to this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window).

Answer (score 0):

If you can rule out compatibility issues (i.e. no Safari users) I would go with [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API). If you can't rule out Safari users, there are some BroadcastChannel polyfills (e.g. [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broadcastchannel-polyfill)) that mimic the same feature, but with some limitations.

Implementation wise - I would create a a service that listens to the broadcasted messages, translates them into application notifications and emits them in a single / multiple observables (depending on your needs).

Your component(s) would then listen to this observable and, when needed, would open the popup (or run some other actions).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance - I'm new with web development, until now I only developed desktop applications. Just want to make sure you suggest some communication method between two instances of the application, one for each window, right? I tried to follow this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window), that allows for a single instance to manage both windows. However I could not figure out how to open a material dialog on the newly opened window. p.s. the browser in my environment can be restricted to Chrome/Firefox. Thanks.